# How Can I apply a substring function on file

Tags: unix

I have a scenario where I have to find the column name for the tables.
I have a large file having around 50K records 
like:

```
PLACES_OF_INDIA_2 :3432123, :Names Expr=('"Table_Name1".Column_1 || '' '' || "Table_Name2".Column_1 || '' '' || "Table_Name3"."Column_2"'), :Name=BCUDB2."Table_Name1".ATTR_VALUE, :Condition=BCUDB2."Table_Name1".Column_1, :Tables=(ABCXYZ."Table_Name1", ABCXYZ."Table_Name2", ABCXYZ."Table_Name3"), :Keys=ABCXYZ."IT_DIM_ANHBUSCH_37560".(M_113478_PQR(Int), M_113443_PQR(Int), M_113484_PQR(Int), M_113470_PQR(Int), M_113468_PQR(Int)), :Attrs=(Name :456866 = ('"Table_Name1".Column_1 || '' '' || "Table_Name2".Column_1 || '' '' || "Table_Name3"."Column_2"', ABCXYZ."Table_Name1", ABCXYZ."Table_Name2", ABCXYZ."Table_Name3"), PLACES_OF_ORIGIN_WineHierarchy_2 :490064736 = ABCXYZ."Table_Name1".ATTR_VALUE)
```

So I want to extract the columns with the line number used for the tables in the file. I have list of tables in separate file like 
**Table_Name1
Table_Name2
Table_Name3**

and I want the output like
1,Column_1
1,Column_2
1,Column_3

Could you please check this

Comment: is there any specific pattern in the file? like, column names will appear only inside brackets or something similar?

Comment: I have table_Name with dot column name. so I just try to look for the table_Name and substring from table_Name to next space but I do not know the sub string function in unix